# React Bootstrap Form.Check working on only double click

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Form.Check element I am using in my React app. For some reason only if I click twice in the check box will the actual check mark change. This is causing my handleChange function to not shoot properly. I already tried using onClick but that will just not allow a change at all to the check box. Can anyone pinpoint what the issue might be?

`<Form.Check  onChange={this.handleChange} inline label="Allow Text" type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.props.allowtext} defaultValue={this.props.allowtext} />`

Answer (score 8):

The problem is on handleChange function. You should remove event.preventDefault(); call.

Comment: Great, it worked! Could you explain why?